# How can I create appropriate pivot table or aggregation table for data below?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({"Client":[0,1,0,1,0], 
"Phone" : ["IPhone", "Huawei", "IPhone", "Samsung", "Huawei"]}))
print(df)
   Client    Phone
0       0   IPhone
1       1   Huawei
2       0   IPhone
3       1  Samsung
4       0   Huawei
```

and 0 means that we lose a client and 1 that our client stay with as. I need table which present how many 0 and 1 has each brand of phone, so i need a table which first column is phone, second column is Client and column client is divided into 2 parts one for value "0" and second for value "1" and the last column which will sum value "0" for each brand of phone and value "1" for each brand of phone.

Comment: I think you need `print (pd.crosstab(df['Client'], df['Phone']))`

Comment: @Adrian, I formatted your code for you - please pay more attention to this next time.